# Java Unsatisfied Link Error IBM CICS Explorer

Tags: java, web, cics

I have got this java project in IBM CICS Explorer and target platform has been set to CICS 5.3. When I run the java class I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com/ibm/cics/server/Task.getCommonData()V
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Task.<init>(Task.java:332)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Task.getTask(Task.java:944)
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You possibly need some DLL in PATH

Comment: Clarification needed — are you running it inside CICS Explorer, or in CICS?

Comment: I am running it in the CICS Explorer

Answer (score 2):

You can develop Java code in IBM CICS Explorer but it is not intended to be run there. As you noted, the target platform is CICS Transaction Server V5.3.

I just created a very simple HelloWorld class using the CICS Task.out PrintWriter. When I click on that in IBM CICS Explorer and say "Run As Java Application", I get something similar to you:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com/ibm/cics/server/Task.getCommonData()V
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Task.<init>(Task.java:332)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Task.getTask(Task.java:944)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:7)
```

Java code for CICS needs to run inside CICS in some type of JVM server, rather than on the development platform.